# Problem to sum two values in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I can't get the right sum of two values.I want to sum the cena1 and kolicina. (cena1+kolicina) and (cena1*kolicina)
My jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function izracunaj() {

    var sum = 0;
    $("#kolicina").each(function() {

    var cena = $("#artikel").val().split("-"); 
    var cena1 = cena[1]; // HERE I GET VALUE 0.17
    var kolicina = $("#kolicina").val(); // VALUE 10

        });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dealing with strings, not numbers, looks like you want floats in which case you would use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get the number from the given string:

```
function izracunaj() {
  var sum = 0;
  $("#kolicina").each(function() {
      var cena = $("#artikel").val().split("-"); 
      var cena1 = parseFloat(cena[1]);
      var kolicina = parseFloat($("#kolicina").val());
      sum += cena1 * kolicinal;
  });
  //use sum
}
```

However, IDs should be unique, so I'm not sure why there's a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) call here, it could be just:

```
function izracunaj() {
  var cena = parseFloat($("#artikel").val().split("-")[0]),
      kolicina = parseFloat($("#kolicina").val());
      sum = cena * kolicinal;
  //use sum
}
```

Comment: This is one thing that ticks me off almost every day in Javascript. Language writers please take note: Addition and concatenation are NOT the same! Don't use the same operator for both!

Answer (score 1):

`$("#kolicina").val();` is probably a string not a number. Try using `parseFloat()`;

Answer (score 1):

You could try using parseFloat on the values. e.g.

```
var answer = parseFloat(cena1) + parseFloat(kolicina);
```

Comment: I tryed var answer = parseFloat(cena1) + parseFloat(kolicina); this option but they don't sum me. i think the problem is in cena1, but don't now how.

Comment: Alen: Could it be that cena is "0,17" instead of "0.17"? The variable name sounds like this is from a country where "," is the decimal separator.